# A strange proof of Glivenko-Cantelli with Dini

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

The following is an excerpt from John Walsh's Knowing the Odds and it concerns the Glivenko-Cantlli theorem.

[image]

The proof first derives the convergence for all rationals and then appeals to Dini's theorem for the uniform convergence part, given that $F^0$ and $F_n^{0}$ are nondecreasing. My question is: how is Dini's theorem applicable here? The version of which I am aware, see for example [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem), requires that the functions $F_n^{0}$ are *continuous* and satisfy *$F_n^{0}(x) \leq F_{n+1}^{0}(x)$*, neither of which is satisfied here. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I agree with you.  Also, that proof does not explicitly state where they are using simultaneous convergence on rationals. It is because, with nondecreasing $F_n(x)$ and continuity of $F(x)$, simultaneous convergence must also hold on all reals.

Comment: It is also not clear to me how they claim it suffices to prove for uniformly distributed random variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, this is not an application of Dini's theorem.  Here is a correct way to finish the proof whenever the distribution function $F(x)$ is continuous over a particular compact set $[a,b]$ of interest. It uses another lemma that I state and prove below.

#### Lemma:

Fix $a,b$ real numbers with $a<b$.  Let $g_n:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be (possibly discontinuous) functions defined for $n \in \{1, 2, 3,...\}$ that converge pointwise to a **continuous** function $g:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.  Further assume that for each positive integer $n$ we have $g_n(x)$ is **nondecreasing** over  $x \in [a,b]$.  Then $g_n\rightarrow g$ uniformly.

Proof: Fix $\epsilon>0$. Since $g(x)$ is continuous over the compact interval $[a,b]$, it must be uniformly continuous.  Choose an integer $k>0$ such that 
$$|x-y|\leq (b-a)/k \implies |g(x)-g(y)|\leq \epsilon$$ 
Divide the interval $[a,b]$ into $k$ disjoint subintervals, each of size $(b-a)/k$.  Let $\{x_0, x_1, ..., x_k\}$ be the gridpoints, where $x_0=a, x_k=b$. We know $g_n(x_i)\rightarrow g(x_i)$ for all $i \in \{0, 1, ..., k\}$ and so we can choose $m$ such that $n\geq m$ implies $|g_n(x_i)-g(x_i)|\leq \epsilon$ for all $i \in \{0, ..., k\}$.

Fix $x \in [a,b]$ and fix $n \geq m$. The value $x$ must be in between two gridpoints, so there is a $j \in \{0, ..., k-1\}$ such that 
$$ x_j \leq x \leq x_{j+1} $$
Since each function $g_n(x)$ is nondecreasing in $x$ we get: 
$$ g_n(x_j) \leq g_n(x) \leq g_n(x_{j+1}) $$
Thus
\begin{align}
&g(x)-\underbrace{|g(x)-g(x_j)|}_{\leq \epsilon} - \underbrace{|g(x_j)-g_n(x_j)|}_{\leq \epsilon} \\
&\leq g_n(x) \\
&\leq g(x) + \underbrace{|g(x)-g(x_{j+1})|}_{\leq \epsilon} + \underbrace{|g(x_{j+1})-g_n(x_{j+1})|}_{\leq \epsilon}
\end{align}
Thus 
$$ g(x) - 2\epsilon \leq g_n(x) \leq g(x) + 2\epsilon$$
That is, $|g(x)-g_n(x)|\leq 2\epsilon$.  This holds for all $x \in [a,b]$. So convergence is uniform.  $\Box$

---

The rest of the proof of Glivenko-Cantelli (with $F(x)$ continuous over an interval $[a,b]$ of interest) uses this lemma together with my first comment that simultaneous convergence over the rationals (with $F_n(x)$ nondecreasing in $x$ and continuity of $F(x)$) implies that we get simultaneous convergence over the reals.

Answer (score 4):

The version of Dini's theorem given in Royden's *Real Analysis* (p.162 in my copy) requires the functions be upper semi-continuous real-valued functions on a "countably compact" domain.  Which these $F_n^0-F^0$ functions on $[0,1]$ are.  ("Countably compact" means every countable open cover has a finite subcover.  $[0,1]$ is countably compact.)

This removes one of the two objections mentioned in the question's last sentence.